# Pine script Syntax error at input '[' array issue

Tags: arrays, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am working on pine script to display alert by looping through list of stocks. I am having issues to fix array related issue which is based on error thrown by the below code

Error at 10:0 Syntax error at input '['.

How can I update my code with any other array alternative?

```
//@version=4
study("Buy Now", overlay=true)

// Input parameters
poleLength = input(title="Pole Length", type=input.integer, defval=30)
flagLength = input(title="Flag Length", type=input.integer, defval=10)
threshold = input(title="Percentage Threshold", type=input.float, defval=2.0, step=0.1)

// Define list of stocks to analyze
stocks = ["COINBASE:LTCUSD", "COINBASE:ETCUSD", "COINBASE:BTCUSD"]

// Loop over each stock in the list
for i = 0 to (len(stocks)-1)
    // Load price data for current stock
    price = security(stocks[i], "15", close)

    // Find bullish flag pattern for current stock
    poleHigh = highest(price, poleLength)
    flagLow = lowest(price, flagLength)
    flagHigh = highest(price, flagLength)
    pattern = poleHigh > flagHigh and poleHigh - flagLow > poleLength * threshold / 100

    // Calculate target price for current stock
    target = pattern ? flagHigh + (flagHigh - flagLow) : na

    // Plot target price for current stock
    //plot(target, color=color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)

    // Send alert if pattern is found for current stock
    if pattern
        alert("Buy: " + syminfo.ticker + " at "+ tostring(price,'#.##') +" and sell at " + tostring(target, "#.##") + " for profit "+ tostring((target-price), "#.##"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use array this way (with bracket) with pinescript.

First, you should use version 5.
Then you will be able to use array like this :

**Declaration of a new array :**

```
MyNewArray = array.new<float>(10, 0.0)
```

see : [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_array{dot}new%3Ctype%3E](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_array%7Bdot%7Dnew%3Ctype%3E)

**Set a new value in the array :**

```
array.set(MyNewArray, 1, 99.99)
```

see : [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_array{dot}set](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_array%7Bdot%7Dset)

**Get a value from an array :**

```
ValueRed = array.get(MyNewArray, 1)
```

see : [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_array{dot}get](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_array%7Bdot%7Dget)